# JavaScript errors are not showing after minification

Tags: javascript, r.js

I'm using r.js to minify js files in cordova based project. Unminified code is working fine, but after minifying nothing is working, not even console.log is working(which was placed in first line of the files which was loaded from index.html file), not even single error is being thrown.

So, I wanted to check whether minified code is throwing any errors at all even though if unminified code has errors. So, I changed some code(by changing object name to `appp` from `app`, and calling `app.initialize`) so that i can get an error in console(in unminified version). As expected I'm getting error in console with unminified version of code, where as minified version of same code(which has error) is not throwing any error.

I should be getting errors in minified code,even though the error is understable.First off I'm not getting any errors.So I don't know why nothing is working after minification, If i get some errors then I can find what exactly the problem with minified code.I don't know why this is happening.

Is anything I'm doing wrong here?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />

      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>

      <title>Title</title>

  </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mainContainer">
            <!-- rootviewTpl -->
        </div>
        <div id="modals-demo">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12">
                    <div id="modal" class="modal"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="loader" id="loader">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/lock-7.10.3.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/jwt-decode.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/config-variables.js"></script>
        <script data-main="js/index.js" src="lib/js/require-2.0.0.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
define([
    "./config"
    ], function(){

    var app = {
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        },
        onDeviceReady: function() {
            require(["js/database/FTMobileDatabase"]);
        }
};

app.initialize();

});
```

**config.js:**

```js
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "lib/js",
  paths: {
    js: "../../js",
    templates:"../../templates",
    jquery:"jquery.min",
    underscore:"underscore.min",
    backbone:"backbone",
    handlebars:"handlebars",
    marionette:"backbone.marionette.min",
    d3: "d3",
    "d3.chart": "d3.chart",
    //materialze library
    velocity:"velocity.min",
    hammerjs:"hammer.min",
    materialize:"materialize.min",
    //date libraries
    moment:"moment",
    hbs: 'require-handlebars-plugin/hbs'
  },
  shim:{
    "jquery":{
      deps:[],
      exports:"jquery"
    },        
    "underscore": {
      deps:[],
      exports: "_"
    },
    "backbone": {
      deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
      exports: "Backbone"
    },
    "marionette":{
      deps:["backbone"],
      exports:"Marionette"
    },
    "handlebars":{
      deps:[],
      exports:"Handlebars"
    },
    "d3": {
      deps:[],
      exports: "d3"
    },
    "d3.chart": {
      deps: ["d3"],
      exports: "d3Chart"
    },
    "materialize":{
      deps:["jquery","velocity","hammerjs"],
      exports:"materialize"
    },
    "moment":{
      deps:[],
      exports:"moment"
    },
    hbs: { // optional
      helpers: true,            // default: true
      templateExtension: 'hbs', // default: 'hbs'
      partialsUrl: ''           // default: ''
    }
  },
  waitSeconds: 0
});
```

**build.json:**

```
({
    appDir: "./www",
    dir:"./www",
    mainConfigFile:"./www/js/config.js",
    modules:[
      {
        name:"js/index",
        include:[
          "js/database/FTMobileDatabase"
        ],
        exclude:[
          "js/config"
        ]
      }
    ],
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    allowSourceOverwrites: true,
    keepBuildDir:true
})
```